# How to match each array field to other field in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have an array as below:

```
const test = [{
    "_id": 1,
    "name": "apple",
    "car": "ford"
},{
    "_id": 2,
    "name": "melon",
    "car": "ferrari"
},{
    "_id": 3,
    "name": "perl",
    "car": "Renaut"
}]
```

And there is are documents of Mongodb as below:

```
[{
  "name": "perl", "company": "A"
},{
  "name": "melon", "company": "B"
},{
  "name": "apple", "company": "C"
},{
  "name": "apple", "company": "D"
},{
  "name": "perl", "company": "E"
},{
  "name": "apple", "company": "F"
}]
```

And I want to get this result using mongodb aggregate:

```
[{
  "name": "perl", "company": "A", testInform: { "_id": 3, "name": "perl", "car": "Renaut"}
},{
  "name": "melon", "company": "B", testInform: { "_id": 2, "name": "melon", "car": "ferrari"}
},{
  "name": "apple", "company": "C", testInform: { "_id": 1, "name": "apple", "car": "ford"}
},{
  "name": "apple", "company": "D", testInform: { "_id": 1, "name": "apple", "car": "ford"}
},{
  "name": "perl", "company": "E", testInform: { "_id": 3, "name": "perl", "car": "Renaut"}
},{
  "name": "apple", "company": "F", testInform: { "_id": 1, "name": "apple", "car": "ford"}
}]
```

I think to use aggregate with `$match` and `$facet`, etc., but I don't know exactly how to do this. Could you recommend a solution for this?

Thank you so much for reading this.

Answer (score 0):

**$lookup** with pipeline keyword

```
db.demo2.aggregate(
    {
      $lookup:
         {
           from: "demo1",
           let: { recordName: "$name"},
           pipeline: [
              { $match:
                 { $expr:
                    { $and:
                       [
                         { $eq: [ "$$recordName",  "$name" ] },
                       ]
                    }
                 }
              },
           ],
           as: "testInform"
         }

    }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `test` array data is stored in a collection then acheiving O/P is pretty straightforward [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) with [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) aggregation

[`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) Why? because the lookup would fetch the joined documents in an array as `testInform`

```
db.maindocs.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "testdocs",
      localField: "name",
      foreignField: "name",
      as: "testInform"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      name: 1,
      company: 1,
      testInform: { $arrayElemAt: ["$testInform", 0] }
    }
  }
]);
```

**Update based on comments:**

The idea is to iterate the [`cursor`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/iterate-a-cursor/) from the documents stored in mongodb  [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) the object from `test` which matches the `name` field, add it to result.

```
const test = [
  {
    _id: 1,
    name: "apple",
    car: "ford"
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    name: "melon",
    car: "ferrari"
  },
  {
    _id: 3,
    name: "perl",
    car: "Renaut"
  }
];


const cursor = db.collection("maindocs").find();
const result = [];

while (await cursor.hasNext()) {
  const doc = await cursor.next();
  const found = test.find(e => e.name === doc.name);
  if (found) {
    doc["testInform"] = found;
  }
  result.push(doc);
}

console.info("RESULT::", result);
```

Comment: test array is not stored in a collection. It's just constant value in js. Could you recommend other solution for that?

Comment: @DDDD Have updated the answer with another solution. Check it out if it works for you. **Note**: I have used `async/await` syntax here, if that's not what you are using, can change the iteration using `callback` style with `forEach`. But the logic remains same.

Answer (score 0):

The aggregation has one stage: Iterate over the `test` array and get the array element as an object which matches the `name` field in both the document and the array (using the [$reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/index.html) operator).

```
const test = [ { ... }, ... ]

db.test_coll.aggregate( [
  { 
      $addFields: { 
          testInform: { 
              $reduce: {
                  input: test,
                  initialValue: { },
                  in: {
                      $cond: [ { $eq: [ "$$this.name", "$name" ] }, 
                               { $mergeObjects: [ "$$this", "$$value" ] }, 
                               "$$value"
                             ]
                      }
               }
          }
      }
  }
] )
```